# Could not find class runtime error -- Eclipse SDK version 3.7.2

Tags: eclipse, build, jar, path, runtime

My code compiles but blows up during runtime.

LogCat file reads: "Could not find class 'com.danielle.algorithm.MergeSort'..."

My setup is where the MergeSort.jar has been added to Referenced Libraries through main project properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries --> Add External JARs.

Before runtime, pressing ctrl+SHIFT+o finds the correct import package. In addition, a Referenced Libraries directory appears, so I'm pretty sure Eclipse handled the additional .jar file.  But for some reason, during runtime, the class in the .jar file can't be found.

I've tried adding external class folder as well without success.

Is there some Eclipse setting I'm not aware of?

Thanks,
Dani

Comment: I've tried adding other .jar libraries to no avail.  I've worked around this problem by adding the package containing the class that's need directly to the project src folder. But I'd still like to know why at runtime the class can't be found using external jars.

Comment: i also having this problem.waiting for answer....

Comment: How do you start your app: Run As within eclipse? In this case check the run configuration tab classpath there must be exists the lib in the classpath. If this is ok check if the same lib or the same lib in an other version is a duplicate entry in the classpath.